# Ruby's &method notation. what is going on?

Tags: ruby

I came across the `&method` in a codebase and I have no idea what is going on. This happens in `irb`:

```
[12,3].map(&method(:to_s))
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
["12","3"].map(&method(:Integer))
#=> [12, 3]
```

What is going on here?

I'm familiar with & being equal to `to_proc`, but I still can't connect the dots here.

Answer (score 7):

In `&method(:to_s)`, `.to_s` is taken from current context (top level object `main`). This version is already bound to receiver and does not accept further arguments. But an argument will be passed by `.map` (each element of the array), that's what it does.

Take a look at this step-by-step reconstruction of what's happening

```
to_s # => "main"
method(:to_s) # => #<Method: main.to_s>
method(:to_s).to_proc # => #<Proc:0x007ff73a27e1e0 (lambda)>
method(:to_s).to_proc.call(12) # => 
# ~> -:6:in `to_s': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
# ~>    from -:6:in `<main>'
```

Now compare to what would happen if it was `.map(&:to_s)`

```
:to_s.to_proc.call(12) # => "12"
```

> I came across the `&method` in a codebase

It can be useful in situations like this: apply a piece of logic to each element, but this logic comes from the current context, completely external to the elements. Take a look at this contrived example:

```
class Tweet
  attr_accessor :text

  def initialize(text)
    @text = text
  end

  def shortened_links
    find_links.map(&method(:shorten_link))
    # same as
    # find_links.map {|link| shorten_link(link) }
  end

  private

  def find_links
    # detect links in text
  end

  def shorten_link(url)
    # use bit.ly or whatever
  end
end
```

Here `links` is a collection of strings. They most certainly can't shorten themselves.

Comment: I don't totally follow why `method(:to_s).to_proc.call(12)` raises an error but `:to_s.to_proc.call(12)` runs without error.

Comment: @Jwan622: because that's how it works. `[12, 13].map(&:to_s)` is equivalent to `[12, 13].map { |elem| elem.to_s }`. Whereas `[12, 13].map(&method(:to_s))` is equivalent to `[12, 13].map {|elem| to_s(elem)}`. Notice the difference?

Comment: And that's just the rule of the language? Does `12.&method(:to_s)`  really just a wrapper over `method(:to_s).to_proc.call(12)`? What does `&method` resolve to anyway?

Comment: @Jwan622: there's no "&method". There's `method` and then there's `&`. See examples above.

Comment: @Jwan622: "Does 12.&method(:to_s) really just a wrapper" - nope, it's invalid ruby, not a wrapper.

Comment: Your contrived example made the understanding much simpler. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code where `&` literal replaced by appropriate block:

```
[12,3].map { |v| to_s(v) }

["12","3"].map { |v| Integer(v) }
```

When it called in console, `to_s` and `Integer` are methods in `Object` class. (Technically `Integer()` is from `Kernel`, that is included in Object).

`to_s` [definition](http://api.rusrails.ru/ruby/classes/Object.html#method-i-to_s) has no arguments, that is why you get `ArgumentError`.

`Integer` [method](http://api.rusrails.ru/ruby/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) could accept 1 or 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`method()` is a way in Ruby to convert a regular method into a passable object. It returns an object of type Method. Given that there is a & in front of the `method()` call, the returned Method object receives a #to_proc message.
Method#to_proc returns a lambda, that passes along the arguments it receives to a call to the original method.

```
class Method
  def to_proc
    lambda { |*args| self.call(*args) }
  end
end
```

This is a simplified view of what happens in the case of #to_s:

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |n| to_s.call(n) } # ArgumentError
```